# Upscaling image with 100% height/width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

First i want to say that i'm working in Wordpress with Woocommerce and theme zeeNoble

I'm currently building a webshop, and i've run into some problem with bad quality image of my products. I searched around and read somewhere that if width and height are both set to auto, the picture will be shown in original quality.

So the width and height on all my product thumbnails are set to auto.

My problem now, is that when i set both `width` and `height` to `auto`, the product thumbnails scales down to a very low image size.

I want to enlarge/scale my product thumbnails without changing the width and height, because if i do that, the images becomes blurry and pixelated.

What do i do here?:)

Comment: **What do i do here?**..showing some relevant code would be a good start!! :)

Comment: You need to improve the quality of the original image. Enlarging the image using CSS will always reduce the quality. You can't put lipstick on a pig and expect it to be beautiful.

Comment: What Tom said. Most probably your source files are small to begin with.

Comment: "I want to enlarge/scale my product thumbnails without changing the width and height" - enlarging/scaling an image **is** changing its width and height

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want your images fluid ?

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change image sizes at *Woocommerce --> Settings --> Catalog --> Image Options*. Don't forget to re-upload your images after that or to use [Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)